# Show loading button during mutation

Tags: react-query

I have a component to create an Announcement that uses a custom hook for mutation -

```js
function CreateAnnouncement() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [isCreating, setIsCreating] = useState(false)
    const { mutate } = useCreateAnnouncement()

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const body = { text }
        mutate({ body }, {
            onMutate: () => {
                setIsCreating(true)
            },
            onSuccess: () => {
                setIsCreating(false)
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <LoadingButton
                variant="contained"
                loadingIndicator="Saving..."
                loading={isCreating}
            >
                Create Announcement
            </LoadingButton >
        </form>
    )
}
```

When the mutation begins, I want to set `loading` to `true` in `LoadingButton`.
But, `mutate` doesn't have a `onMutate` side-effect.

So, is there a way to know when mutation starts using `mutate`?

## UPDATE

The accpeted answer shows one way of solving the problem.
I found out a simpler way -
Use `isLoading` from `useMutation` hook inside the `LoadingButton` component -

```js
const { mutate, isLoading } = useCreateAnnouncement()
<LoadingButton
   loadingIndicator="Saving..."
   loading={isLoading}
>
    Create Announcement
</LoadingButton >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling a loading flag when the callback passed as [onMutate](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation) option is executed should be correct, so you have got that right. You can unset the flag using `onSettled`, so that loading stops being indicated on success and on error.

Might the error be in the LoadingButton?
Can you add `console.log()` statements in lines inside the `onSuccess` function and before `CreateAnnouncement` returns and log `isCreating`?

UPDATE

If you want to define `onMutate` in the component, your custom hook needs to forward these options to the `useMutation` call:

```js
const createProjectError = 'SOME ERROR MESSAGE';

type Error = ErrorType<typeof createProjectError>;

export const useCreateProject = (
    config?: MutationOptions<Project, Error, CreateProject>
) => {
    // invoke some other hooks

    return useMutation<Project, Error, CreateProject>(
        async createModel => {
            const response = await api.createProject(createModel);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(createProjectError);
            }

            await queryClient.invalidateQueries(QueryKeys.GET_PROJECTS);

            return response.body;
        },
        {
            onError: () => {
               // some side effect
            },
            onSuccess: () => {
                // some side effect
            },
            ...config,
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: `useMutation` has the `onMutate` side-effect, but `mutate` doesn't. And, I want to set `loading` inside the component , so I need a way to figure out when mutation starts using `mutate`

Comment: I see now, sorry. Updated the answer

Comment: So, I just need to pass the `onMutate` from my component to the custom hook. Wonderful!...Thank you so much!